# Как подобрать универсальные параметры для вызова функции

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, сортировка, шаблоны-с++

Нужно написать шаблон функции для сортировки двумерных массивов. У меня сортировка каждой строки отдельно от меньшего к большему пузырьком. Шаблон  вызывается, если перегрузить его параметрами void Sort(T (*mas)[6], int n, int m) и void Sort(double(*mas)[3], int n, int m). Есть ли универсальные параметры, чтобы не нужно было делать перегрузку?

```
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void Sort(T(*mas)[6], int n, int m)
{
    int k = 0;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = m-1; j > i; j--)
            {
                if (mas[k][j] < mas[k][j - 1]) 
                {
                    T tmp = mas[k][j];
                    mas[k][j] = mas[k][j - 1];
                    mas[k][j - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        k++;
    } while (k < n);
}
void Sort(double(*mas)[3], int n, int m)
{
    int k = 0;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (int j = m - 1; j > i; j--)
            {
                if (mas[k][j] < mas[k][j - 1]) swap(mas[k][j], mas[k][j - 1]);
                /* {
                    T tmp = mas[k][j];
                    mas[k][j] = mas[k][j - 1];
                    mas[k][j - 1] = tmp;
                }*/
            }
        }
        k++;
    } while (k < n);
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int const n = 4, m = 6;
    int i_mas[n][m];
    //cout << "Целочисленный массив\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            i_mas[i][j] = rand() % 10;
            cout << i_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    int const n2 = 4, m2 = 3;
    double d_mas[n2][m2];
    //cout << "Вещественный массив:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2; j++)
        {
            d_mas[i][j] = (rand() % 10 + rand() % 10*0.1);
            cout << d_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    char c_mas[n][m];
    //cout << "Символьный массив:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            c_mas[i][j] = rand() % 26 + 97;
            cout << c_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    Sort(i_mas, n, m);
    //cout << "\nЦелочисленный массив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) cout << i_mas[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    Sort(d_mas, n2, m2);
    //cout << "\nВещественный массив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2; j++)
        {
            cout << d_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    Sort(c_mas, n, m);
    //cout << "Символьный массив после сортировки:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << c_mas[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы, указывая метку `шаблоны`, обратили внимание на ее описание? *Для пометки вопросов, имеющих отношение к C++ templates, используйте другую метку - [шаблоны-c++]!*

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить параметр размера массива

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void Sort(T (*mas)[N], int n, int m)
```

Но это очень половинчатое решение. Потому что имеет смысл добавить и второй размер, и тогда вам не придется передавать в функцию размеры отдельно:

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
void Sort(T (&mas)[N][M])
{
    int k = 0;
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = M-1; j > i; j--)
            {
                if (mas[k][j] < mas[k][j - 1]) 
                {
                    T tmp = mas[k][j];
                    mas[k][j] = mas[k][j - 1];
                    mas[k][j - 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        k++;
    } while (k < N);
}
```

После этого при вызове функции ей достаточно передать только массив:

```
Sort(d_mas);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает

Comment: А вы можете объяснить, почему не работает так void Sort(T (*mas)[N][M])? Почему именно ссылка нужна, но не указатель?

Comment: В принципе можно, но тогда надо таскать за собой разыменование, что не очень-то удобно: https://ideone.com/WyRmLp